# What is Azula doing differently which causes her fire to be Blue?

Tags: avatar

When Azula does her firebending the flames are blue rather than red/orange that every other firebender has. we know that the fire is only blue when it''s came from her firebending as when she is fighting Aang and Zuko in that abandoned town (shortly after Toph joins when Appa is molting) she uses her firebending to set the walls of a building of fire but the flames are only blue for a moment and return to the normal colour.

So i am wondering what Azula is doing differently with her Firebending to make her flames blue?

Comment: Has been answered: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/why-is-azulas-fire-blue

Comment: to show that she is unique and to stand out from the other firebenders also her being a child firebending- prodigy

Answer (score 5):

So I'm going to get all physics-y here, but bear with me.

Thinking in terms of real world physics, some flames will burn blue depending in what it is that you're burning. Certain elements burn blue, other burn green, etc. The reason for this is a little bit long, so I won't write it here. This wouldn't be the case with Azula, since we can almost definitely inffer that she's burning the same thing every other firebender burns: the particles in the air.

So why are her flames blue? Basically, the color of something you see relates to the frequency of the light coming from the object, which is directly proportional to how much eletromagnetic energy that thing is emitting. Basically, red light has low frequency (low energy) and blue light has high frequency (high energy). So if something burns blue, it means it is being burned with lots of energy: AKA it's really fucking hot.

So to summarize: Azula's fire if blue because it burns hotter, which follows along well with the whole "she's a genius" thing.

You can also think of it from an emotional view point: since lightning is called "fire without heart", maybe you could think that Azula's fire being blue relates to that. Since she is quite heartless and mentally deranged, her emotional state is shown via her flames' colors.

Answer (score 1):

third answer of the day. i'm answering this because you don't have an accepted answer. the first answer is technically correct. in again the avatar wiki, it was stated that she is a prodigy who can bend more powerful flame: the blue flame. exact words: Blue fire: Only Azula has demonstrated blue firebending. While not to be confused with lightning, blue fire also seems to possess more physical force and produces a combustive effect that is more intense than that of normal fire. so basically, the fire is blue because it's more powerful than the red/orange/yellow flames.